# is there any way to find which process created a file in windows c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, kernel, kernel-module, msdn

Ultimately I'm trying to get the process id of the program which created a new file.

For example: if I install a application through an installer and when new files are created I want to know the process ID of the Installer which created the new files.

Comment: No, you can find out which process(es) has a file open but the creator of a file isn't recorded, even if it was the pid might not exist any more

Comment: I doubt that the process ID of the process that created the file is stored in the NTFS file system. However, I believe that it is possible to determine which processes have an open handle to this file, so you could maybe obtain the desired information that way. I believe it is possible to also monitor certain kernel events such as creating files, so that you receive a notification whenever a file is created, including the process ID of the process that created the file. But I don't think that this is possible to obtain this information afterwards, as it is not logged by the OS.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel thanks for the answer and is there any links or resource on monitoring file creation using kernel events? I searched for it and did not find anything.

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at [Sysinternals Process Utilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-utilities) on the official Microsoft site. Of particular interest may be the utilities "Process Explorer", "Process Monitor" and "Handle".

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle)

Comment: You can create an audit on file creation in the parent directory. That will log info into the security event log.

Comment: Guys I'm Trying to achieve this using c++ program.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you couldn't get the process id of the program that created the new file via winapi.